# wildcard setup with 2 nginx servers

Tags: nginx, https, ssl-certificate

I just need a bit of help with https config for nginx using a wildcard domain name across 2 servers.

we have the wildcard domain lets call it *.mydomain.com

We currently have a server shop.mydomain.com and that's running with the wild card cert just fine. What we want to do now is set up a community site called club.mydomain.com and run that from a new machine.

Do I just copy the existing .crt and .key files from the existing server and copy them to the new machine and adjust my domain name accordingly?

possible examble ....

```
server {
listen        443;
    server_name  club.mydomain.com 

    ssl             on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.com.key;

    }
```

Or is there some sort of ssl key related stuff I have to do ?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 2):

If you have a wildcard SSL certificate, then that's all you have to do. They are locked to domain names, not to specific servers or IP addresses.